# version AEM 6.5, is it possible to combine classes?

Tags: css, aem

I am working on AEM V.6.5 and writing properties for responsive.
I need to include every GridColumn here as code below.

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .aem-Grid.aem-Grid--default--12 > {
        .aem-GridColumn.aem-GridColumn--default--12,
        .aem-GridColumn.aem-GridColumn--default--11,
        .aem-GridColumn.aem-GridColumn--default--10,
        .aem-GridColumn.aem-GridColumn--default--8,
        .......
        .aem-GridColumn.aem-GridColumn--default--1 {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
}
```

It is very long!  I am looking for a short way to write.  I try code (below), but somehow it doesn't work.

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
        .aem-Grid.aem-Grid--default--12 > {
            .aem-GridColumn.aem-GridColumn--default--* {
                width: 100%;
            }
        }
    }
```

Please give me a hand.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to use LESS CSS you could use a [Recursive Mixin](http://lesscss.org/features/).

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .aem-Grid.aem-Grid--default--12 > {
        .generate-columns(12);
    }
}

.generate-columns(@n, @i: 1) when (@i =< @n) {
    .aem-GridColumn.aem-GridColumn--default--@{i} {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .generate-columns(@n, (@i + 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We have an `OOTB` file present to make any changes for the AEM grid templates. That will be way easier for you to do.

File is : `grid.less`

Path: `ui.apps/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/{client-name}/clientlibs/clientlib-site/less/grid.less`

[Here's](https://medium.com/adobetech/customizing-the-aem-grid-3ff9c2121a36) a helpful article